# how to get Doxygen to work with Fortran interface statements?

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I am working on free software project CCR, which allows climate and other Earth science users to add additional compression methods to netCDF. See https://github.com/ccr/ccr.

I have a Fortran file, and Doxygen is giving me the following warnings:

```
/home/ed/noaa/ccr/fsrc/ccr.F90:19: warning: Member nc_def_var_bzip2(ncid, varid, level) (function) of class ccr::nc_def_var_bzip2 is not documented.
/home/ed/noaa/ccr/fsrc/ccr.F90:36: warning: Member nc_def_var_lz4(ncid, varid, level) (function) of class ccr::nc_def_var_lz4 is not documented.
/home/ed/noaa/ccr/fsrc/ccr.F90:27: warning: Member nc_inq_var_bzip2(ncid, varid, bzip2p, levelp) (function) of class ccr::nc_inq_var_bzip2 is not documented.
/home/ed/noaa/ccr/fsrc/ccr.F90:44: warning: Member nc_inq_var_lz4(ncid, varid, lz4p, levelp) (function) of class ccr::nc_inq_var_lz4 is not documented.
```

But I have documented these functions. The line numbers doxygen is complaining about are part of interface statements:

```
module ccr

  !> Interface to initialization function.
  interface
     function nc_initialize_ccr() bind(c)
       use iso_c_binding
     end function nc_initialize_ccr
  end interface

  !> Interface to C function to set BZIP2 compression.
  interface
     function nc_def_var_bzip2(ncid, varid, level) bind(c)
       use iso_c_binding
       integer(C_INT), value :: ncid, varid, level
     end function nc_def_var_bzip2
  end interface

  !> Interface to C function to inquire about BZIP2 compression.
  interface
     function nc_inq_var_bzip2(ncid, varid, bzip2p, levelp) bind(c)
       use iso_c_binding
       integer(C_INT), value :: ncid, varid
       integer(C_INT), intent(inout):: bzip2p, levelp
     end function nc_inq_var_bzip2
  end interface

  !> Interface to C function to set LZ4 compression.
  interface
     function nc_def_var_lz4(ncid, varid, level) bind(c)
       use iso_c_binding
       integer(C_INT), value :: ncid, varid, level
     end function nc_def_var_lz4
  end interface

  !> Interface to C function to inquire about LZ4 compression.
  interface
     function nc_inq_var_lz4(ncid, varid, lz4p, levelp) bind(c)
       use iso_c_binding
       integer(C_INT), value :: ncid, varid
       integer(C_INT), intent(inout):: lz4p, levelp
     end function nc_inq_var_lz4
  end interface
```

How do I get Doxygen to see the documentation of the interfaces?

Comment: Did you try moving the comments into the interface block?

Comment: The *"Documentation at other places"* section of the [Doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) may contain the answer you are looking for. I have not tried it but the solution might be as simple as adding `\interface` at the beginning of the comment.

Comment: Doxygen is complaining abou the fact that the methods as defined in the interface are not documented, looks to me that the interface is documented or did I miss something (maybe add an image and indicate what you are missing). Which version of doxygen are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the @fn tag, and specify the entire function signature, after module_name::fn_name::. Here's an example from another project:

```
  interface
     !> @fn bacio_module::baciol::baciol(mode, start, newpos, size, no, nactual, fdes, fname, datary)
     !> Do a bacio operation.
     !>
     !> @param mode
     !> @param start
     !> @param newpos
     !> @param size
     !> @param no
     !> @param nactual
     !> @param fdes
     !> @param fname
     !> @param datary
     !>
     !> @author Ed Hartnett @date 21-10-18
     integer function baciol(mode, start, newpos, size, no, nactual, &
          fdes, fname, datary) bind(C)
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: mode
       integer(c_long), value, intent(in) :: start, newpos
       integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: size
       integer(c_long), value, intent(in) :: no
       integer(c_long), intent(inout) :: nactual
       integer(c_int), intent(inout) :: fdes
       character(kind=C_char), intent(in) :: fname(*)
       character(kind=C_char), intent(in) :: datary(*)
     end function baciol
  end interface
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use `\copydoc` here or `\snippet{doc}`